# Use temprary label for pandas.DataFrame.plot in legend

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I have a pandas.DataFrame object of which column names are very ugly:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ugly name1':[1,2,3], 'ugly name2':[2,3,4]})
```

I'd like to plot that dataframe with pretty data name in the legend. I know how to rename the column but hope to keep that ugly name after plotting.

**My question** is what is the simplest way of the same process of below.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ugly name1':[1,2,3], 'ugly name2':[2,3,4]})
column_names = df.columns
df.columns = ['pretty1', 'pretty2']
df.plot()
df.columns = column_names
print df.columns #=> should print ['ugly name1', 'ugly name2']
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manually alter the legend after the plot is drawn:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'ugly name1':[1,2,3], 'ugly name2':[2,3,4]})

df.plot()
plt.legend(['pretty1', 'pretty2'],loc='upper left')
```